# Trouble with component re-rendering in basic React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a basic React app that renders a list of books from an array and has a form which pushes another book object on to the array. I was thinking that modifying the book array is a change to props which will cause the `Post` component to re-render, but I can't get `Post` to re-render unless I force it to manually by clinking a link and navigating back. I believe I have attached all the relevant components as well as the books array. I used create-react-app to set-up the React environment. **React version - 15.4.1.** Many thanks for any help you can provide!

**Edit:** 
*I have refactored a little and created a github repo to make everything more clear.*

[Github Repo](https://github.com/harrygz889/book-list)

```js
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import {Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory} from 'react-router'

import App from './App'
import Display from './Display'
import Content from './Content'

//stylesheet
import './index.css'

//import posts array
import postsArray from './postsArray'

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={Display} entries={postsArray}></IndexRoute>
      <Route path="view/:id" component={Content} entries={postsArray}></Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react'

import Post from './Post'


class Display extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    this.props.route.entries.push({
      title: this.titleInput.value,
      author: this.authorInput.value,
      body: this.bodyText.value
    })
    event.preventDefault()
  }


  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <Post entries={this.props.route.entries}/><br /> <br />
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            Title:<br />
            <input type={"text"} ref={(titleInput) => this.titleInput = titleInput}  className="input" />
          </label><br />
          <label>
            Author:<br />
            <input type="text" ref={(authorInput) => this.authorInput = authorInput} className="input" />
            </label> <br />
          <label>
            Body:<br />
            <textarea ref={(bodyText) => this.bodyText = bodyText} className="textAreaInput"/>
          </label> <br />
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Display
```

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {Link} from 'react-router'


class Post extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    console.log("insinde post initial", this.props.entries)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="postsWrapper">
        {this.props.entries.map((entry, index) => (
          <div key={index} className="divMargin">
            <Link to={"view/" + index } className="postLink">
                <h1 className="postH titleFont">{entry.title}</h1>
                <h2 className="authorFont authorMargin">{entry.author}</h2>
            </Link>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Post
```

```js
var posts = [
  {
    title: "A Walk in the Woods",
    author: "Bill Bryson",
    body: "A very enjoyable book!"
  },
  {
    title: "Bridge Over The River Kwai",
    author: "Pierre Boulle",
    body: "I have never read this book. Not ever."
  },
  {
    title: "Do Not Sell at Any Price",
    author: "Amanda Petrusich",
    body: "Will you please please please give me this book when you're done?"
  },
  {
    title: "Just Kids",
    author: "Patti Smith",
    body: "This is a national book award winner! Wow!"
  }
]

export default posts
```

Comment: The use of 'entries' on router looks a bit uncommon to me. Can you explain further why you want to populate posts array this way?

Comment: And, since you are logging posts array, can your array props be successfully updated in Post component?

Comment: I sort of arbitrarily decided to pass the array as props from the router. It might not be the best decision, but even if I pass entries as props from the display component I get the same problem. Also the Post component is really only in charge of rendering each Post and such is disconnected from the form where the updating happens, but I feel it should still re-render because of the props change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this (and learn something) by using `setState` and `.concat` instead of mutating the Array directly with `.push`. The final solution was something like:

```
this.setState({
  entries: this.state.entries.concat([{
    title: this.titleInput.value,
    author: this.authorInput.value,
    body: this.bodyText.value
  }])
})
```

The actual changes are in the github repo if interested.

*Thanks to @Stanley Luo for his help in debugging.*

Answer (score 1):

By default, if props (in your case, the posts array) change, the related component should update without trouble.

But since your `Post` component refuse to update, I recommend you use [shouldComponentUpdate()](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) to have an inspection, checking whether the props are updated accordingly.

`shouldComponentUpdate` is always called before the render method and enables to define if a re-rendering is needed or can be skipped.

`componentWillUpdate` gets called as soon as the the shouldComponentUpdate returned true. Any state changes via this.setState are not allowed as this method should be strictly used to prepare for an upcoming update not trigger an update itself.

If you are not familiar with lifecycle methods, check this [article](http://busypeoples.github.io/post/react-component-lifecycle/).

In your case, try

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  return nextProps.entries.length !== this.props.entries.length;
}

componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  // posts array did change, do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried implementing the shouldComponentUpdate method which didn't trigger a re-render. I put a console.log above the return just to see when it was being called but couldn't get anything to log as though shouldComponentUpdate was never being called.

Comment: @HarryZumwalt That means neither your props nor states were changed; mostly likely it's the props you got through router were not updated accordingly. Try a new way to get the posts array - I recommend fetching the array from `Redux store` using `componentWillMount()` lifecycle method.

Comment: Hmm interesting. I've already tried bringing it in through props directly via `Display` (not Router). I've also tried setting the state equal to the array inside the constructor/componentWillMount hook with no success. I'm sure Redux shouldn't be necessary. Stumped on this.